# Как поднять "слой" canvas выше python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Сделал кнопки и разместил необходимые изображения в tkinter. По задумке поезд должен двигаться по путям, поэтому нужен метод `canvas.move()`. Но canvas либо находится выше всего интерфейса (если создаю экземпляр после отрисовки кнопок и тд.), либо ниже (если раньше) и иконка поезда находится под всем. Как можно решить эту проблему? Если переделывать все изображения под canvas, то придется менять их размер, и переписывать большую часть кода. Поэтому хотелось бы избежать этого (если конечно, есть такой вариант)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1390x1040")
        self.title("Система контроля движения поездов")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.color_for_label = "#424242"

        self.button_font = ("Arial", 22, "bold")
        self.canvas = Canvas()
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", expand=True)
        self.configure(background="green")

        self.img_timetable = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("images/timetable_icon.png"), size=(35, 35))
        self.img_close = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("images/close_icon.png"), size=(35, 35))
        self.route = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("images/route.png"), size=(80, 850))
        self.img_main_station = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("images/main_station.png"), size=(50, 50))
        self.img_station = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("images/station.png"), size=(30, 30))
        self.img_train = PhotoImage(file="images/train.png")

        self.button_timetable = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Расписание", height=50, width=500, font=self.button_font,
                                              image=self.img_timetable, command=self.button_timetable, corner_radius=15)
        self.button_timetable.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.button_close = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Закрыть", height=50, width=500, font=self.button_font,
                                          image=self.img_close, command=self.button_close, corner_radius=15)
        self.button_close.place(x=520, y=10)

    def button_timetable(self):
        print("Нажал")

    def button_close(self):
        quit()

    def start_train(self):
        self.trains = []
        train = self.canvas.create_image(0, 200, image=self.img_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте методы `tag_lower()` и `tag_raise()` объекта Canvas.

Так:

```py
canvas.tag_raise(obj)
```

Или так:

```py
canvas.tag_lower(obj)
```

[Перевод](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959968/19509421)